# tcpSlaveAgentListener is invalid 404 Not Found

Tags: jenkins

I have an external installation of jenkins and when I try to set up slaves for jenkins in Openshift I get this error.
I follow every step from this guide https://blog.openshift.com/jenkins-slaves-in-openshift-using-an-external-jenkins-environment/

```
Nov 05, 2019 1:46:26 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: http://jenkins01:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/  is invalid: 404 Not Found
java.io.IOException: http://jenkins01:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/  is invalid: 404 Not Found
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:202)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:523)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:474)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out. We had another service running on port 50000 (jenkins tunnel), I modify it to an available port and it started to work. It was misleading because in the error it shows 8080, but actually it uses 50000.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone looking for the real explanation for this... You must configure a different port for jnlp i.e. `50000`. The catch is that you need to provide the `JENKINS_URL=http://jenkins:8080` and `JENKINS_TUNNEL=jenkins:50000`.
If you try to hit `50000` on both the URL and TUNNEL you will get the error of

> 50000/tcpSlaveAgentListener invalid 404 not found.

If you try to hit `8080` on both URL AND TUNNEL you will get an error like

> Incorrect acknowledgement sequence, expected 0x000341434b got 0x485454502f".

I hope this saves someone time

Comment: I got rid of the tunnel setting and things started to work for me. Installing Jenkins via Helm.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to go to `Manage Jenkins`, `Security`, section `Agents`, select `Random` and click `Save`.

The issue was that the TCP port for inbound agents is disabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

Actually for me I just went to Manage Jenkins -> Security -> In Agent section, It was disabled by default. Then Setting it to random worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, Jenkins was running on an AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster as a stateful set and we started seeing the same error after Jenkins upgrade. Deleting its pod so that it can get created and deployed again and then restarting it from the Jenkins console fixed the issue for us.